# My unittest reports a failure (AssertionError: List differ) but they don't appear to differ, why?

Tags: python, unit-testing

This is my unittest code:

```
def testExtractObject(self):
    self.maxDiff = None
    objects = Script("compare.py").extractObjects()
    self.assertListEqual([Object('ClassA',2,5,None),
                    Object('ClassB',1,3,None),
                    Object('ClassC',0,2,None)], objects)
```

This is the failure message:

```
AssertionError: Lists differ: [Object(name='ClassA', meth... != [Object(name='ClassA', meth...

First differing element 0:
Object(name='ClassA', methods=2, lines=5, description=None)
Object(name='ClassA', methods=2, lines=5, description=None)

[Object(name='ClassA', methods=2, lines=5, description=None),
 Object(name='ClassB', methods=1, lines=3, description=None),
 Object(name='ClassC', methods=0, lines=2, description=None)]
```

I cannot figure out what the difference between the lists are from this message, anyone have some insight into this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to tell python how to determine whether or not two objects are equal. You do this by adding an `__eq__` function to your class

```
class SomeObject(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.a == other.a and self.b == other.b
```

Then objects which pass this test will be considered equal. By default the equality test for objects is `left is right` which is only true when they are the same object, not two objects with the same values.